# Zendframework(1.12.11) view helper not found in phpunit

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I have following directory structure for view helper in my zendframework project

```
 --application
       --views
         --helpers
            --Test.php
```

and configuration setting in application.ini is

```
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

and configuration in Bootstrap.php is

```
$view->setHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/views/helpers/");
```

in Test.php file naming convention is

```
class Zend_View_Helper_Test extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {}
```

and I am using helper function in module wherever I need it.When I run project via browser, application working fine without any error, but when I invoke phpunit for same application via command line I am getting error something like

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include_once(Zend\View\Helper\Test.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in D:\
zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework-1.12.11\library\Zend\Loader.php:134
```

that means it's going to find Test.php file in zend server library view folder.I am not getting why it's working via browser and not working in phpunit via command line.

Comment: Can you please share the command you have used to run PHPUnit and the config file? Which version of PHPUnit you are using?

Comment: command : phpunit -c phpunit.xml, phpunit version is 3.7.21 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. I have replace my configuration setting of application.ini

```
resources.view.helperPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers"
```

with

```
resources.view.helperPath.Application_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/helpers/"
```

and changed naming convention of Test.php with

```
class Application_View_Helper_Test extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {}
```

now zend loder will try to find view helper in application directory rather than Zend